# Using loop to check if variable is in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

So for class I'm making a crummy text adventure game. I want to check what the user enters against my dictionary of acceptable words. However, when I do as follows I get a 'TypeError: 'set' object is not subscriptable'. How would I go about fixing this?

Small section of code for the 'game':

```
def butts():
    southLib={"long thing", "rough thing", "cylinder thing", "floor thing", "home"}

    userPoop = str(input("Would you like to poop in the long thing, rough thing, cylinder thing, floor thing, or home? None?"))

    while southLib[userPoop] == None:
        print("I do not understand")
        userPoop = str(input("Would you like to poop in the long thing, rough thing, cylinder thing, floor thing, or home? None?"))

butts()
```

Comment: You're creating a set, and you're trying to use it as a dict. They're different types.  A dict is used to map keys to values; a set just to collect a bunch of values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perform proper containment checking.

```
while userPoop not in southLib:
```

Comment: AWESOME. I knew it was simple but just couldn't figure out a way to phrase the question.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if something's not in a set, just use the `not in` operator:

```
>>> my_set = {"foo", "bar", "baz"}
>>> "foo" not in my_set
False
>>> "qux" not in my_set
True
```

(Similarly, you can use `in` to check if something *is* in a set.)